# Hosting a URL in the second column of backstage view

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I am developing a VSTO excel add-in and have added a tab in the backstage UI using the ribbon.xml file. Now, in my tab, I have added a button. On clicking that button, I want to render a url (say https://www.google.com) in the second column. Is it possible? Or opening a dialog is the only way to achieve this?

I read about the structure and schema but couldn't find a way to do it.

```
<firstColumn>
    <group id="FirstGroup" label="Group One" helperText="Information about the 
           first group">
          <primaryItem>
            <button id="BigButton" label="Primary Button" 
                onAction="OpenDialog"/>
          </primaryItem>
    </group>
</firstColumn>

<secondColumn>
    <!-- Render a webpage here -->
</secondColumn>
```

In my example, on clicking the button, the method OpenDialog should render a webpage in the second column.

Comment: Do you mean adding a web browser control to the second column, then in the button click do a `webBrowser1.Navigate("Google.com");`? I don't think the ribbon supports that, I haven't seen 3rd party Ribbon controls that have that either. Typically you have a user control and open that from the ribbon buttons.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thanks for replying. Well, I just want to render the url in the second column. WebBrowser opens in a new window, if I am correct. Just wanted to know if there's any way I could achieve my use case.

Comment: Add a label control to the second column and give it blue forecolour text with an underline. Then in the label_click open a web browser control.